# Leverage and profit proportion

Tags: percentages

Suppose me and my friend invest in the same stock but he has 10% more than me. I want to have the same amount as him, but I have no money to buy 10% more, so I'm gonna leverage my position to profit more % than him and reach him. My question is: how do I calculate the minimum profit required to achieve it given a specific level of leveraging?

For example, if I have 100 shares at 1 dollar each, my friend has 110 shares. I leverage at 2,1x, so I borrow  110 dollars from the broker and operate at 210. If the stock grows 10%, I'll profit 21 dollars (10% of 210) and my friend will profit 11 (10% of 110). Now I pay the 110 of the broker and take my 21 profit and buy more 10 shares at 1,1. So, for a given leveraging (2,1x) I need 10% of profit to reach my friend. But what if I leverage at 2x, 3x, 1,5x etc?

Comment: This is not clear.  Are you ascribing some cost to the leverage?  If so, how much?  If not...well, if you have $2x$ shares and your friend has $1.1x$ then your profit will always exceed his (assuming there is some profit).

Comment: @lulu, yes. If I have 100 and he has 110, I must profit more than him to neutralize his 10% advantage. Suppose I leverage 2,1x, so if it grows 10%, he's gonna have 121 and I'm gonna have 121 too (I'm operating 2,1x which is 210).

Comment: I don't understand.  Stock prices may climb, but the number of shares you have don't (unless you buy more).

Comment: The way leverage works:  Suppose the stock currently trades at $\$1$ a share and you own $100$ shares.  You want to buy more, so you use those shares as collateral for a loan.  Say your broker will loan you $\$50$ against those shares.  You could then buy another $50$ shares in which case you would own $150$ shares but would still need to pay interest on that $\$50$ loan.  Your friend owns $110$ but has no loan to pay off.  If you meant something other than this you should edit your post to clarify.

Comment: @lulu, I'm gonna buy more shares with the profit. With 2,1x leveraging I'm gonna profit 21, and then I will have money to buy those 10% more shares and reach my friend.

Comment: @lulu, I'm gonna borrow 110 and operate with 210. With 10% of profit it will turn 221. So I pay the 110 of the broker and take my 21. Buy more 21 shares and now I'm 1-1 with my friend.

Comment: Just edited my question. Hope it is a bit clearer now.